# Me salta la comprobación del while

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando que mediante esta comprobación verifique si lo introducido por pantalla, una vez pasado a minúsculas. Es igual a `"adolfo"`. Si no lo es que este en bucle preguntando la misma pregunta hasta que el usuario introduzca bien el nombre. Pero independientemente de que lo ponga bien o mal no realiza la comprobación.

```js
var nombre = prompt("Nombre del primer presidente español");
while (nombre.toLowerCase==adolfo){
    alert("Introduze un parametro válido");
    var nombre = prompt("Nombre del primer presidente español");
}
```

Comment: adolfo es una `variable` o un `string?`

Comment: adolfo es el parametro que el programa espera para que en caso de ser igual salga del bucle. adolfo va dentro de la variable nombre

Comment: adolfo es un valor de la variable nombre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adolfo es valor de la variable nombre , alli esta el error.
adicional cambie el while por un `do-while`

```js
do{
    alert("Introduze un parametro válido");
    var nombre = prompt("Nombre del primer presidente español");
    console.log(nombre);
}while (nombre.toLowerCase()!="adolfo");
```

Comment: diste en el clavo. Gracias

Comment: aunque ahora tan solo me hace la comprobacion una vez. es raro mirare a ver. por que en lo que me has pasado lo ejecuto y esta en bucle repitiendolo hasta que lo introduzco bien

Comment: [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/toLowerCase) es un método, **No una propiedad** , debe finalizar con **()**

Comment: perfecto compañero ;D

Answer (score 3):

Esta muy bien dicho lo que dice **JackNavaRow**, solo una pequeña modificación ya que el mensaje  **alert("Introduce un valor valido")** se va a mostrar, sin embargo aun no hemos ingresado un nombre.

```
    var primeraVez = true;
    var nombre;
    do{
      if(primeraVez){
      nombre = prompt("Nombre del primer presidente español");
      primeraVez = false;
      }
      else{
      alert("Introduze un parametro válido");
      nombre = prompt("Nombre del primer presidente español");
      }
    }while (nombre.toLowerCase() != "adolfo")

    alert("Nombre del primer presidente español: " + nombre);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Intenta encerrando la palabra adolfo entre comillas así:

```
while (nombre.toLowerCase() == 'adolfo'){
            alert("Introduze un parametro válido");
            var nombre = prompt("Nombre del primer presidente español");
        }
```

Saludos !!

Comment: También tienes toda la razón, no me había fijado en eso !!